# creating multiple tables

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am calling a child component which is app-table-multi-sort from deals-transaction.component.html ,  the data from the table is from the result of _pageEventDealsList which is  `this.table.data = res.items;`

What I want is how do we create different set of table with different this.tableOptions based on dealType value as you can see on the object below.

If dealType is qual to "A" then show data in separate table , if dealType is qual to "B"  show data on separate table , so in this example there are 2 tables since there 2 different dealType .

Right now my current code they are all in one table which is wrong.

but we should only reuse the app-table-multi-sort to do that , is it possible without keeping on repeating the app-table-multi-sort >?. Any idea guys. Thank you.

#sample data table result screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pVsV.png)

#deals-transaction.component.html

```
 <app-table-multi-sort (dataServiceEvent)="dataServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions" [tableData]="data"
      (tableActionsEvent)="tableActions($event)" (editRowEvent)="editDeal($event)"></app-table-multi-sort>
```

#tscode - deals-transaction.component.ts

```
export class DealsTransactionComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TableMultiSortComponent, { static: true }) tableMultiSortComponent: TableMultiSortComponent;
  transactionSubscripion: Subscription;
  tableOptions: any;
  @Input() transaction: any;
  isLoading: boolean;
  accountId: any;
  data: any;
  searchInput: string;
  leaseId : number;
  table: any;
  DEAL_TYPES = DEAL.TYPES;
  menuItems: any[];
  totalDealsForApproval: number;
  totalDeals: number = 0;
  hasPendingAprroval = false;
  subscription!: Subscription; 
  propertyId: any;

  constructor(
    private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private trasactionService: TransactionService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private dealService: DealService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private route: Router,
    private dealTransactionService: DealTransactionService
    
  ) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.leaseId = this.transaction.leaseId;
    this.propertyId = this.transaction.propertyId;    
    const currentAccountDetails = localStorage.getItem('currAcct') as any;
    if (currentAccountDetails) {
      this.accountId = JSON.parse(currentAccountDetails).accountId;
    }

    this.menuItems = [
      { dealType: this.DEAL_TYPES.IDLE_DISPOSITION, buttonText: this.DEAL_TYPES.IDLE_DISPOSITION.text , },
      { dealType: this.DEAL_TYPES.PARTNERSHIP, buttonText: this.DEAL_TYPES.PARTNERSHIP.text },
      { dealType: this.DEAL_TYPES.PORTFOLIO_MANAGEMENT, buttonText: this.DEAL_TYPES.PORTFOLIO_MANAGEMENT.text , condition: !this.leaseId },
    ]

    this.tableOptions = {
      columns:[
        {id:'name',name:'Deal Name',subId:'type', subtitle:'Deal Type'},
        {id:'annualRentProposed',name:'Annual Rent (Proposed)', subId: 'annualRentCurrent', subtitle:'Annual Rent (Proposed)'},
        {id:'firmTermRemain',name:'Firm Term Remaining', subId: 'firmTermAdded', subtitle:'(Current)'},
        {id:'maxTerm',name:'Max Available Term'},
        {id:'cash',name:'Cash Contribution'},
        {id:'action', name: 'Actions', actions:[
          {icon:'file_copy', name:'Copy', class:'primary-color' , },
          {icon:'delete', name: 'Delete', class:'mat-error ml-7px'},
          {icon:'forward', name: 'For Approval', class:'primary-color'}
        ]}
      ]
    }

    this.subscription = this.dealTransactionService.dataSubject.subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.editDeal(data);
     });

  }
 dataServiceEvent(item) {
    this.table = item;
    if(this.table) {
      this.reloadDeals();
    }
  }
  reloadDeals() {
    this._pageEventDealsList();
  }
  public _pageEventDealsList() {
    this.searchInput = '';
    const status = 'Draft'
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        status,
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false)))
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => this.notificationService.showError(err),
        next: (res) => {
          this.table.totalItemCount = res.totalItemCount;
          this.table.lastItemOnPage = res.lastItemOnPage;
          this.table.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
          this.table.data = res.items;
        },
        complete: noop,
      });
  }
```

#sample data result from _pageEventDealsList

```
[
    {
        "id": 183,
        "name": "A",
        "dealType": "A",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": null,
        "firmTermRemaining": null,
        "firmTermAdded": null,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "capitalContribution": null,
        "createdOnString": "09/29/2021",
        "fileName": null,
        "serverFileName": null,
        "size": null,
        "absoluteUri": null,
        "sentTo": null
    },
    {
        "id": 186,
        "name": "B",
        "dealType": "B",
        "annualRentProposed": null,
        "annualRentCurrent": null,
        "firmTermRemaining": null,
        "firmTermAdded": null,
        "maxAvailableTerm": null,
        "capitalContribution": null,
        "createdOnString": "09/29/2021",
        "fileName": null,
        "serverFileName": null,
        "size": null,
        "absoluteUri": null,
        "sentTo": null
    },
]
```

Comment: What about `totalItemCount`, `lastItemOnPage`, `totalElements` will it be same as got from api?

Comment: @navnath still the same Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, Let me know if you did not understand anything.

```
// Declare two variables 
dealsByTypeA$  = of([]);
dealsByTypeB$  = of([]);

const allDeals$ = this.dealService
      .getAllDeals(
        status,
        this.accountId,
        this.transaction.id,
        this.table.pageIndex + 1,
        this.table.pageSize,
        this.searchInput,
        this.table.sortParams,
        this.table.sortDirs
      )
      .pipe(
            tap(res => {
                if(res){
                    this.table.totalItemCount = res.totalItemCount;
                    this.table.lastItemOnPage = res.lastItemOnPage;
                    this.table.totalElements = res.totalItemCount;
                }
            }),
            catchError(error => this.handleError(error)),
            finalize(() => (this.isLoading = false))
        );

// Observable with dealType with 'A'        
this.dealsByTypeA$ = allDeals$ .pipe(
    map(res => res.items.filter(o => o.dealType === 'A'));
);

// Observable with dealType with 'B'
this.dealsByTypeB$ = allDeals$ .pipe(
    map(res => res.items.filter(o => o.dealType === 'B'));
);

handleError(error: any): Observable<PagedModel>{
    this.notificationService.showError(error);
    return of({ totalItemCount: 0, lastItemOnPage: 0, firstItemOnPage: true, isLastPage: true, items: [] });
}
```

In template:

```
<app-table-multi-sort
    ...
    [tableData]="dealsByTypeA$ | async">
</app-table-multi-sort>

<app-table-multi-sort
    ...
    [tableData]="dealsByTypeB$ | async">
</app-table-multi-sort>
```

If you have only two dealTYpes then you can also solve this problem very easily using RxJs [Partition](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/partition) operator

Comment: how about on <app-table-multi-sort (dataServiceEvent)="dataServiceEvent($event)" [tableOptions]="tableOptions" [tableData]="data"
      (tableActionsEvent)="tableActions($event)" (editRowEvent)="editDeal($event)"></app-table-multi-sort>       Sir ?

Comment: I am receiving an error navthah https://imgur.com/a/HjKT2rE

Comment: What is return type of `this.dealService
   .getAllDeals`

Comment: Is it PagedModel? Share Its structure. Are you going to have only two  types of `dealType`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/lPl3lHo , here Sir

Comment: this is the original one before I change into your code https://imgur.com/a/838oyQM

Comment: check updated answer.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/stMAOms

Comment: is there a bit simplier way to do this Sir ?

Comment: Are you goin to have only two types of dealTypes? If yes then there is a way else this is the proer way by my knowledge

Comment: The error you shared segnifies that `dealType` is not a property inside `BaseModel`

Comment: In the future, if dealType is increased then it will be so easy for you to add them, you just need to copy-paste one of the `dealsByType$` snippets and modify it accordingly. And by using the `async` pipe you do not need to take care about subscribing, unsubscribing.

Comment: Hi Sir , I tried the code no errors but the data is not displaying ...https://imgur.com/a/b27hmam

Comment: Have you used Async pipe `[tableData]="dealsByTypeB$ | async"`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7sPhnyc yes Sir I did use it

Comment: Can you share any desk id i will solve it

Comment: what is desk ID sir ?

Comment: https://anydesk.com/en where i can see your screen.

Comment: this is the code Sir https://imgur.com/a/WQuTc0o

Comment: the res from the  const allDeals$ = this.dealService is empty Sir

Comment: Now the data is showing Sir , just one last question sir , how do we create a condition that each dealsByType has its own   this.tableOptions?

Comment: Yes Sir , there is a type of deal which table options has only 3 columns , column names

Comment: Can we just declare a new this.tableOptions object Sir every deal type ?

Comment: Yes, if your tableOptions are not coming from backend..Mam.. any problem ask now

Comment: but where do we add that condition inside and after calling allDeals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237848/discussion-between-brinda-anand-and-navnath).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464476/adding-key-value-to-an-object-in-typescript